# How to make a customer class for iteration fields Using FileHelper library

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using excellent [FileHelpers library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). I have a question for iteration fields of Customer class. 
As you can see below class, L1 ~ L51 is just field of datas.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public string Time;
    public double L1;
    public double L2;
    public double L3;
    public double L4;
    public double L5;
    public double L6;
    public double L7;
    public double L8;
    public double L9;
    public double L10;
    public double L11;
    public double L12;
    public double L13;
    public double L14;
    public double L15;
    public double L16;
    public double L17;
    public double L18;
    public double L19;
    public double L20;
    public double L21;
    public double L22;
    public double L23;
    public double L24;
    public double L25;
    public double L26;
    public double L27;
    public double L28;
    public double L29;
    public double L30;
    public double L31;
    public double L32;
    public double L33;
    public double L34;
    public double L35;
    public double L36;
    public double L37;
    public double L38;
    public double L39;
    public double L40;
    public double L41;
    public double L42;
    public double L43;
    public double L44;
    public double L45;
    public double L46;
    public double L47;
    public double L48;
    public double L49;
    public double L50;
    public double L51;
    public string last;
}
```

**EDITED**
Data Format is just :I have a title of first row. How can I build the customer class ?

```
    Time,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L11,L12,L13,L14,L15,L16,L17,L18,L19,L20,L21,L22,L23,L24,L25,L26,L27,L28,L29,L30,L31,L32,L33,L34,L35,L36,L37,L38,L39,L40,L41,L42,L43,L44,L45,L46,L47,L48,L49,L50,L51,
2013-08-29 오후 4:41:21,12.817,34.447,14.302,74.672,76.082,2.766,27.258,10.532,21.266,3.546,68.156,8.31,19.472,7.199,51.964,6.975,44.893,55.766,134.145,145.979,16.246,74.095,99.121,49.657,22.815,14.174,44.615,61.78,48.514,52.316,-1.357,8.641,10.265,15.562,47.328,12.561,14.676,13.234,55.211,29.533,49.059,42.693,52.754,14.9,71.916,61,94.955,82.832,47.04,39.178,66.191,
    2013-08-29 오후 4:41:21,12.817,34.447,14.302,74.672,76.082,2.766,27.258,10.532,21.266,3.546,68.156,8.31,19.472,7.199,51.964,6.975,44.893,55.766,134.145,145.979,16.246,74.095,99.121,49.657,22.815,14.174,44.615,61.78,48.514,52.316,0,8.641,10.265,0,0,0,14.676,13.234,55.211,29.533,49.059,42.693,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39.178,0,
    2013-08-29 오후 4:41:21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,44.615,61.78,48.514,52.316,0,8.641,10.265,0,0,0,14.676,13.234,55.211,29.533,49.059,42.693,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39.178,0,
    2013-08-29 오후 4:41:22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Is it possible to write like below ? or any suggestions ?

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public string Time;
    public double[] L;
}
```

Comment: If it is not possible, just throw that library from the window, because if it forces you to have 50 fields, it is nuts! :)

Comment: i dont get the point in this library

Comment: @Nicolas, the best way to use FileHelpers is to think of the record class as just a 'spec' for your file format. You use it to describe the file using only public fields (yes this goes against C# best practice, I know, but remember it's just the spec). Once you have loaded the file into an array of MyFileHelpersClass[] which FileHelpers does very well, then you can map the values (e.g., with a foreach) to a more sensible class with properties, methods, additional functionality, etc.

Comment: There are other methods though. but thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, just use the `FieldArrayLength` attribute:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public string Time;

    [FieldArrayLength(51)]
    public double[] L;

    public string last;
}
```

You have to provide the `FieldArrayLength` attribute because of the last column in your data (which seems to be always empty). Note that you could make `last` private instead of public if you're bothered about the field.

Another possible solution is to use `double?` instead of `double`, but then you'll have to deal with the trailing `null` values.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public string Time;

    public double?[] L;
}
```

A third solution is to provide a value the data in the last column should default to, using the `FieldNullValue` attribute, e.g.:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
    public string Time;

    [FieldNullValue(Double.NaN)] 
    public double[] L;
}
```

---

**Edit:** To skip the first row of your file, use the `IgnoreFirst` attribute:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst(1)]
public class Customer
{
    public string Time;

    [FieldArrayLength(51)]
    public double[] L;

    public string last;
}
```

Comment: I have edited little more about title of field. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Thanks again. Very nice. [link](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/attributes.html) There is no "FieldArrayLength" attribute. Is it old version or not ?

Comment: I tried the version thats available via NuGet. It's 2.9.9 or something like that.